# Remove space in a data without visualise it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have these input-boxes which I did some controls on them using jQuery. If the inserted number is longer than 3 digits it will add space to them on `blur`, and after re-entering to the input-box (`focus`) it will delete the spaces. These two functions work fine !

The problem is that when I want to send these data (click over Check Me button), due to the fact that on `blur` I added spaces to them, these entries are not considered as number `(isNaN)`.

[image: Problem]

I want a solution to check these data (without changing them on the page), by using the same function on `focus` (included in my codes), in order to check them correctly and not getting error because of the spaces.

```js
   $(function() {
     $('.ndInbox').blur(function() {
       try {
         // Get your formatted number
         var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
         if (isNaN(formatted) || $(this).val() == "") {
           return;
         }
         // Split off any decimal value (there should be one)
         var sections = formatted.split('.');
         // Replace every third digit with a space
         sections[0] = sections[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, " ");
         // Output the updated and rejoined sections
         $(this).val(sections.join('.'));
       } catch (err) {
         alert(err);
       }
     });
     $('.ndInbox').focus(function() {
       if ($(this).val() != "") {
         var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
         if (isNaN(formatted)) {
           return;
         }
         $(this).val(formatted);
       }
     });
   });

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#btn').click(function() {
       /*
              //it should happen here !!!
              $('.ndInbox').DontKnowWhat(function() {
                if ($(this).val() != "") {
                  var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
                  if (isNaN(formatted)) {
                    return;
                  }
                  $(this).val(formatted); // this one should not be displayed in page
                }
              });
              // till here
       */

       $("#avPurchase01").removeClass("ndLabelRed");
       $("#avPurchase02").removeClass("ndLabelRed");
       $("#avPurchase03").removeClass("ndLabelRed");

       if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn02Id').val())) {
         $("#avPurchase01").addClass("ndLabelRed");
       }
       if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0sd').val())) {
         $("#avPurchase02").addClass("ndLabelRed");
       }
       if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0232').val())) {
         $("#avPurchase03").addClass("ndLabelRed");
       }
     });
   });
```

```css
.ndInbox {
  background-color: white;
  width: 390px;
  height: 42px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.ndLabel {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
.ndLabelRed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase01">Average, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn02Id" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase02">Budget, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn0sd" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase03">Salary, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn0232" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn">
  Check ME
</button>
```

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/reshadgp/0fxoj8mr/1/)

Comment: parseFloat('123 123.00'.split(' ').join(''))

Comment: @YuraYakym var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2); works fine as well, the problem is in the commented function in my codes, which I don't know how to do your suggestion on each of them individually

Comment: `parseFloat('123 123 123'.replace(/\s/g,''))`

Comment: @Rajesh please take a look at my codes, the problem is not how to remove spaces. is how to do that for each of my entries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create plugin that will return number:

```
  $.fn.number = function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      return Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
    }
  };
```

and use it like this:

```
   if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn02Id').number())) {
     $("#avPurchase01").addClass("ndLabelRed");
   }
   if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0sd').number())) {
     $("#avPurchase02").addClass("ndLabelRed");
   }
   if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0232').number())) {
     $("#avPurchase03").addClass("ndLabelRed");
   }
```

Comment: But if you please update my jsFiddle, I will be really thankfull

Answer (score 1):

You can check `isNaN` condition like :

```
if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0sd').val().split(" ").join(""))) {
         $("#avPurchase02").addClass("ndLabelRed");
       }
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fxoj8mr/2/)

```js
   $(function() {
     $('.ndInbox').blur(function() {
       try {
         // Get your formatted number
         var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
         if (isNaN(formatted) || $(this).val() == "") {
           return;
         }
         // Split off any decimal value (there should be one)
         var sections = formatted.split('.');
         // Replace every third digit with a space
         sections[0] = sections[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, " ");
         // Output the updated and rejoined sections
         $(this).val(sections.join('.'));
       } catch (err) {
         alert(err);
       }
     });
     $('.ndInbox').focus(function() {
       if ($(this).val() != "") {
         var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
         if (isNaN(formatted)) {
           return;
         }
         $(this).val(formatted);
       }
     });
   });

   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#btn').click(function() {
       /*
              //it should happen here !!!
              $('.ndInbox').DontKnowWhat(function() {
                if ($(this).val() != "") {
                  var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
                  if (isNaN(formatted)) {
                    return;
                  }
                  $(this).val(formatted); // this one should not be displayed in page
                }
              });
              // till here
       */

       $("#avPurchase01").removeClass("ndLabelRed");
       $("#avPurchase02").removeClass("ndLabelRed");
       $("#avPurchase03").removeClass("ndLabelRed");

       if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn02Id').val().split(" ").join(""))) {
         $("#avPurchase01").addClass("ndLabelRed");
       }
       if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0sd').val().split(" ").join(""))) {
         $("#avPurchase02").addClass("ndLabelRed");
       }
       if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0232').val().split(" ").join(""))) {
         $("#avPurchase03").addClass("ndLabelRed");
       }
     });
   });
```

```css
.ndInbox {
  background-color: white;
  width: 390px;
  height: 42px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.ndLabel {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
.ndLabelRed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase01">Average, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn02Id" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase02">Budget, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn0sd" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase03">Salary, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn0232" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn">
  Check ME
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

First `$(function(){})` is a shorthand for `$(document).ready()`, so you should have only 1.

Second, in my understanding, its better to create a function that returns Form data, instead of creating every time.

---

I have taken privilege of updating your code. Hope it helps!

#### Changes:

1. Created 2 variables, `ids` and `s_ids`. `ids` is a parent array of all ids. `s_ids` is a subset array consisting ids, that needs special handling.
2. Created functions `getData()`, `cleanData()`, `validateAndUpdateUI()` and `registerEvents()`. `getData()` will return value of all ids in `ids`. `cleanData()` will remove spaces for all ids in `s_ids`. `validateAndUpdateUI()` will loop over all ids and validate them. `registerEvents()` is just a wrapper function for all event bindings. This will just help your code to be clean and maintainable.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0fxoj8mr/6/).

```js
var ids = ["lpcfIn02Id", "lpcfIn0sd", "lpcfIn0232"];
var s_ids = ["lpcfIn02Id", "lpcfIn0sd", "lpcfIn0232"];

function getData() {
  return ids.map(function(id) {
    return {
      id: id,
      value: $("#" + id).val()
    };
  });
}

function cleanData(data) {
  data.forEach(function(o) {
    if (s_ids.indexOf(o.id) > -1)
      o.value = o.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  });
}

function initUIState() {
  ids.forEach(function(id) {
    $("#" + id).parent().prev().removeClass("ndLabelRed");
  });
}

function validateAndUpdateUI(data) {
  data.forEach(function(o) {
    if (isNaN(o.value))
      $("#" + o.id).parent().prev().addClass("ndLabelRed");
  });
}

function registerEvents() {
  $('.ndInbox').blur(function() {
    try {
      // Get your formatted number
      var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
      if (isNaN(formatted) || $(this).val() == "") {
        return;
      }
      // Split off any decimal value (there should be one)
      var sections = formatted.split('.');
      // Replace every third digit with a space
      sections[0] = sections[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, " ");
      // Output the updated and rejoined sections
      $(this).val(sections.join('.'));
    } catch (err) {
      alert(err);
    }
  });
  $('.ndInbox').focus(function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
      var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
      if (isNaN(formatted)) {
        return;
      }
      $(this).val(formatted);
    }
  });
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    initUIState();
    var data = getData();
    cleanData(data);
    console.log(data);
    validateAndUpdateUI(data);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  registerEvents();
});
```

```css
.ndInbox {
  background-color: white;
  width: 390px;
  height: 42px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 #C2C2C2;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.ndLabel {
  color: #999;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}
.ndLabelRed {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase01">Average, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn02Id" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase02">Budget, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn0sd" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="ndLabel" style="position: relative; width: 470px; top:-4px" id="avPurchase03">Salary, &euro;:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="lpcfIn0232" class="ndInbox" type="text" value="" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="btn">
  Check ME
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but before I got another solution. I voted up your question :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use some variables to store the data before calculation?

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
   var average = parseFloat($('#lpcfIn02Id').val().replace(/\s/g,''));
   var budget = parseFloat($('#lpcfIn0sd').val().replace(/\s/g,''));
   var salary = parseFloat($('#lpcfIn0232').val().replace(/\s/g,''));
   /*
          //it should happen here !!!
          $('.ndInbox').DontKnowWhat(function() {
            if ($(this).val() != "") {
              var formatted = Number($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, '')).toFixed(2);
              if (isNaN(formatted)) {
                return;
              }
              $(this).val(formatted); // this one should not be displayed in page
            }
          });
          // till here
   */

   $("#avPurchase01").removeClass("ndLabelRed");
   $("#avPurchase02").removeClass("ndLabelRed");
   $("#avPurchase03").removeClass("ndLabelRed");

   if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn02Id').val())) {
     $("#avPurchase01").addClass("ndLabelRed");
   }
   if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0sd').val())) {
     $("#avPurchase02").addClass("ndLabelRed");
   }
   if (isNaN($('#lpcfIn0232').val())) {
     $("#avPurchase03").addClass("ndLabelRed");
   }
 });
```

Comment: Because these is just an example and in my real page I have lot's of numbers and if I want to use variable for all of them, my code will be really messy